# Hibernate connections strange behavior

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jpa, paypal

We are making a web application where we are using PayPal for the users to make a subscription but we are having some problems. When we are creating accounts, logging in and doing various requests we have no problems but when we are making 4-7 simultaneous payments our connection pool is not behaving properly.

This is an image of the number of connections. You can see the number of connections spikes after a few payments. When we reset the server it drops down. The last time where the connections are high, you can see what's happening when the server gets to take care of the connection itself - 
[as you can see it takes hours to drop connections.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvZTm.png)

This is our persistence.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
version="2.1">

 <persistence-unit name="up2u">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/up2u_user?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="up2u_user2"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="e2f2c2ac87"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="true"/>


            <!-- Connectionpool-->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="200" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="10" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="400" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireIncrement" value="10"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts" value="3"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay" value="100"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.checkoutTimeout" value="300" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="300" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxConnectionAge" value="300" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxStatementsPerConnection" value="2" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Why is the number connections not dropping when doing payments? The CPU and memory aren't working significantly more when doing payments and I can see nothing more than the connections building and a few more packets/second in firewall throughput.

Comment: The persistence.xml configures your pool of database connections. Are you sure that the connections shown in the graph are database connections? Your web app probably has a pool of threads for incoming connections, a pool of outgoing connections (e.g., to PayPal), etc.

Comment: Thank you rob. You are probably on to somthing there. Any suggestions on how I can manage that type of connections? Since the server seams to crack when only a few payments are made and won't respond in a few hours it's kind of a problem and I'm kind of new to this situations.